# Numpy/Pandas clean way to check if a specific value is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I check if a given value is NaN?

e.g. `if (a == np.NaN)` (doesn't work)

Please note that:

- Numpy's `isnan` method throws errors with data types like string
- Pandas docs only provide methods to drop rows containing NaNs, or ways to check if/when DataFrame contains NaNs. I'm asking about checking if a specific value is NaN.
- Relevant Stackoverflow questions and Google search results seem to be about checking "if any value is NaN" or "which values in a DataFrame"

There must be a clean way to check if a given value is NaN?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the inate property that `NaN` != `NaN`

so `a == a` will return `False` if `a` is `NaN`

This will work even for strings

Example:

```
In[52]:
s = pd.Series([1, np.NaN, '', 1.0])
s

Out[52]: 
0      1
1    NaN
2       
3      1
dtype: object


for val in s:
    print(val==val)
True
False
True
True
```

This can be done in a vectorised manner:

```
In[54]:
s==s

Out[54]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

but you can still use the method `isnull` on the whole series:

```
In[55]:
s.isnull()

Out[55]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

**UPDATE**

As noted by @piRSquared if you compare `None==None` this will return `True` but `pd.isnull` will return `True` so depending on whether you want to treat `None` as `NaN` you can still use `==` for comparison or `pd.isnull` if you want to treat `None` as `NaN`

Comment: Important to note that Pandas `isnull` will count `None` as a null value.  However, `None == None` evaluates to `True`.  This is differs from `NaN`'s behavior.  So if `a = np.array([None, np.nan])` and we evaluated `a == a`, we'd get `array([True, False])`

Comment: @piRSquared what version of numpy,pandas,python are you using as I don't see this, also if this is True wouldn't you then get the same result when calling `b.isnull()` in your answer which is not what I observe

Comment: @piRSquared I'm running python 3.6.0, numpy 1.11.3 and pandas 0.22.0

Comment: @piRSquared I do agree about the `None==None` but for some reason I don't observe this

Comment: pandas 0.22, numpy 1.14, python 3.6.  `a = np.array([None, np.nan]); print(a == a, pd.isna(a), sep='\n\n')`

Comment: @piRSquared I get a strange result `[True True]` for both I also get a warning: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: FutureWarning: numpy equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
  if __name__ == '__main__':` maybe I should upgrade numpy

Comment: What are your versions?

Comment: @piRSquared python 3.6.0, numpy 1.11.3 and pandas 0.22.0 it looks like it's trying to perform an identity comparison rather than equality which is weird judging by the warning

Comment: I'll attempt on numpy 1.11.3 to verify.  Good to note version disparity though.

Comment: @piRSquared I'm going to update to the latest and retry this

Comment: @piRSquared so I finally updated my python environment, I needed to delete some stuff to recover HD space hence the delay, and the result is different I get `[True False]` and `[True True]` running `a = np.array([None, np.nan]); print(a == a, pd.isna(a), sep='\n\n')` so there does seem to be a difference in numpy behaviour

Answer (score 11):

Pandas has [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html), [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html), [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isna.html), and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notna.html)

These functions work for arrays or scalars.

---

### Setup

```
a = np.array([[1, np.nan],
              [None, '2']])
```

---

### Pandas functions

```
pd.isna(a)
# same as
# pd.isnull(a)

array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]])
```

---

```
pd.notnull(a)
# same as
# pd.notna(a)

array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True]])
```

---

### `DataFrame` (or `Series`) methods

```
b = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

---

```
b.isnull()
# same as
# b.isna()

       0      1
0  False   True
1   True  False
```

---

```
b.notna()
# same as
# b.notnull()

       0      1
0   True  False
1  False   True
```

Comment: Didn't know about `isna` unclear to me apart from less typing what is different from `isnull`

Comment: @EdChum I don't think there is one, with the exception of 2 less chars.

Comment: Looks like it was added in [`0.21.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#na-naming-changes) for consistency, probably why I didn't notice it

Comment: Thanks, `isnull` seems to work on a single value. By the way, I was asking about checking a specific value without checking all values in the Series/DataFrame.